# Select dropdown using xpath in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, xpath, puppeteer

I want to make puppeteer to select from dropdown box using:

> await page.select(selector , values);

Can i use xpath in order to search 'values' parameter ?

Here is the example of the code :

```
<select id="dropdown" >
 <option> No value selected </option>
 <option value = "0|XXA1|RandomString"> Option 1 </option>
 <option value = "0|XXA2|RandomString"> Option 2 </option>
 <option value = "0|XXA3|RandomString"> Option 3 </option>
</select>
```

From the example , i want to select an option where the value contains "XXA1".

Here is the way, how i want to get the option.

> await page.select('#dropdown' , '//select[@id="dropdown"]//option[contains(@value , "XXA1")]');

The 'values' in puppeteer maybe cannot be replace with xpath argument. CMIIW.
But could i solve it in another way ?

Any helps would be appreciated . Many thanks ! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use the xpath selector method with a very non-googleable name of [$x](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagexexpression):

```
page.$x('//select[@id="dropdown"]//option[contains(@value , "XXA1")]')
```

Comment: I believe this only gets the element. It doesn't set the select element's value to XAA1

Answer (score 0):

```
let optElementHandle = page.$x('//select[@id="dropdown"]//option[contains(text() , "XX")]')
let optValue = optElementHandle.getProperty('value');
await page.select(`#dropdown option[value='${optValue}']`)
```